# I merge 2 points and i want to get it back no ctrl + z available

Tags: edit-mode

[image]

By mistake I merge this 2 points and I want to get them back how I can do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the shortcut <kbd>V</kbd> to rip the vertice.